# Red, blue and yellow points

Tags: mathematics, geometry

In the plane, there are $r+b+y=15$ points, of which 
$r\ge2$ points are colored red, 
$b\ge2$ points are colored blue, and 
$y\ge2$ points are colored yellow.

- If we consider all pairs of red and blue points and add up their distances then the sum is $51$.
- If we consider all pairs of red and yellow points and add up their distances then the sum is $39$.
- If we consider all pairs of yellow and blue points and add up their distances then the sum is $1$.

> Determine all possible values for $r$ and $b$ and $y$.

Comment: "all pairs of red and blue points" - does this include red-red, blue-blue and red-blue, or only red-blue?

Comment: @astralfenix: "all pairs of red and blue points" only includes red-blue (but not red-red and blue-blue).

Comment: Are the points allowed to coincide?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The updated answer is:

> $r = 8$
>  $b = 4$
>  $y = 3$

I'm making this answer a community wiki, since I made a mistake at the end of my original answer and it was Van.Graaf who delivered the final punch.

Reasoning:

> Let's consider all the tri-colored triangles (e.g. one vertex red, one vertex blue, one vertex yellow) and apply triangle inequalities.  The sum of lengths of all the red-blue segments must be no greater than the sum of all lengths of all the red-yellow segments and all the blue-yellow ones.
>
>  What is the sum of lengths of all the red-blue segments? It is $51y$ (each red-blue pair is counted $y$ times and the sum of pair lengths is $51$).  Of red-yellow segments — $39b$, of blue-yellow — $r$. Therefore, the inequalities are:
>
>
>  $51y \le 39b + r$
>  $39b \le 51y + r$
>  $r \le 51y + 39b$
>  $r + b + y = 15$
>
>  The only triple $(r, b, y)$ which satisfies the above set of constraints is $(8, 4, 3)$.
>
>  Here's the space of possible solutions, with blue on the $x$ axis and yellow on the $y$ axis:
>
>
>  [image: Diagram]
>
>  The graph in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/per0tkuthz

A set of points with this property can be realized

> in something of a trivial way:  construct a triangle $RBY$ with sides $RB = 51/32$, $RY = 39/24$, and $BY = 1/12$.  Note that these lengths satisfy the triangle inequalities.  Then place all eight red points at $R$, all four blue points at $B$, and all three yellow points at $Y$.  A scale drawing of this configuration is below;  the points used are $(0,0)$, $(0,1/12)$, and $(\sqrt{5247935}/1536, 991/1536)$.
>  
>  
>  [image]

Comment: "The sum of lengths of all the red-blue segments must be no greater than the sum of all lengths of all the red-yellow segments and all the blue-yellow ones." This is not true. Consider 100 red points and one yellow, all in the same place and one blue segment 1 unit away. Then the lengths of red-blue segments add up to 100, while the lengths of yellow-blue and red-yellow ones add up to 1.

Comment: @BaSzAt If you consider all possible triangles (there are 100 of those, choose one of the reds, the blue and the yellow), then the sum of red-blue and yellow-blue over all triangles is the same: 100. PS: Bolo is too fast, I was about to post the same thing.

Comment: @ffao I think I understand now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @BaSzAt Consider that if a >= b and c >= d then a+c >= b+d. This means that if you add the red-blue segments of the first 2 triangles, the result must be no greater than the result of adding the other segments. This can be extended for 3, 4, 5 etc up to all the triangles

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

> $b = 4, ~~  r = 8, ~~  y = 3$.

Reasoning:

> Consider all tri-colored triangles and apply triangle inequalities. The sum of lengths of all the red-blue segments must be no greater than the sum of all lengths of all the red-yellow segments and all the blue-yellow ones.
>  
>  
>  The sum of lengths of all red-blue segments is $51y$. The sum of lengths of all red-yellow segments is $39b$. The sum of lengths of all blue-yellow segments is $r$.
>  
>  
>  Therefore, the inequalities are:
>
>  $51y \le 39b + r$
>  $39b \le 51y + r$
>  $r \le 51y + 39b$
>  $r + b + y = 15$
>
>  The integer solutions are $b = 4, ~~  r = 8, ~~  y = 3$ and $b = 1,~~   r = 13, ~~  y = 1$. The first solution has $b\ge2$.

Comment: I can vouch for the correctness of the calculations, that is, those are indeed the only integer solutions to the system of inequalities and equality. That said, I still think it should be shown whether or not the diophantine solution has a geometric realisation on the plane.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri:  I added a (semi-trivial) geometric realization of these points in the community wiki answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Are they allowed to coincide? That's a bit of a bummer, haha.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri:  Yeah, it's not terribly interesting.  I suspect, however, that this solution could be continuously deformed to another one where the points aren't all degenerate.  After all, we have 30 free variables (x and y coords for 15 points) and only 3 constraints, so one would expect the solution space to be 27-dimensional.